# Extracting data from a Parse.com class and into an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, parse-platform

I'm using the following query to get some data from a Parse.com class.

What I would like to do is extract the `Rating` object from the `NSArray` rateObjects. How would I go about doing this?

thanks for any help

```
 PFQuery *rateQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Rating"];
        [rateQuery whereKey:@"photo" equalTo:self.photo];
        [rateQuery includeKey:@"photo"];

    rateQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    rateQuery.limit = 20;

    [rateQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *rateObjects, NSError *error)
     {
         if( !error )
         {
             NSLog(@"rateObject %@", rateObjects);

         }
     }
     ];
```

Here's the `NSLog` output:

```
rateObject (
    "<Rating:w9ENTO29mA:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x1e0a5380>\";\n    Rating = 4;\n    fromUser = \"<PFUser:uV2xu0c3ec>\";\n    photo = \"<Photo:Rv4qqrHUPr>\";\n    toUser = \"<PFUser:uV2xu0c3ec>\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:uV2xu0c3ec>\";\n}",
    "<Rating:t3pjtehYR0:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x1e0f9f90>\";\n    Rating = 5;\n    fromUser = \"<PFUser:uV2xu0c3ec>\";\n    photo = \"<Photo:Rv4qqrHUPr>\";\n    toUser = \"<PFUser:uV2xu0c3ec>\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:uV2xu0c3ec>\";\n}"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `NSArray` will contain `PFObjects`, which you can treat in a similar way to a dictionary. In the query you ran above you received two rating objects back. If that's not what you wanted (you only wanted a single object) you may want to revisit how you're querying your data.

Assuming your `Rating` class in Parse contains a key called `Rating` you would access it like this:

`[rateObject objectForKey:@"Rating"]`

You can also use the new modern literal syntax if you like - `rateObject[@"rating"]`

You'll need to iterate through your array to view all the rating objects that have been returned, so you'll probably end up with something like this:

```
for (id item in rateObjects) {
    int ratingVal = [[item objectForKey:@"Rating"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"Rating: %d", ratingVal);
}
```

You may find Parse's [iOS documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#overview) helpful - and if you're not sure what the code above actually does, you may want to review arrays and how they work in Objective-C.

Comment: thanks for the post. Using the following I get the output "Rating:0". However in the NSArray output I get Rating = 4.   NSDictionary *rateObject;
                 
                 int ratingVal = [[rateObject objectForKey:@"Rating"] intValue];
                 NSLog(@"Rating: %d", ratingVal);

Comment: There was a typo in the code - sorry. I accidentally had you called `objectForKey` on `rateObjects`, it should be `item`. Try it again with the modified version (I've corrected my answer)

Comment: that worked perfectly! thanks so much for your help. I was stuck on that for some time. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:

```
[rateQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *rateObjects, NSError *error)
 {
     if( !error )
     {
       NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      [data addObjectsFromArray:rateObjects];
       NSArray *rating_data = [data valueForKey:@"Rating"];
       NSLog(@"%@",[rating_data objectAtIndex:0]);

     }
 }
];
```

I hope this will help you.