# Parse Product Link Returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink, parse-platform

I am using the Parse.com Store template and I am having trouble accessing parts of my data browser. I need to access a column called 'link' from the data browser and I do not seem to be able to. If I run  `linkLabel.text = self.product[@"link"];` and then NSLog it `NSLog(@"%@", linkLabel.text]);`
The value is returned as null.

So I decided to check what the value of 'link' is. I ran     `NSLog(@"%@", self.product[@"link"]);` and still it returned null. I thought well there is something wrong with 'link' so i tried 'name'     `NSLog(@"%@", self.product[@"name"]);`still... nothing (it returns (null)).

So I have no idea how to access link or name from my ViewController. I have even added `@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *product;` and still nothing.

I am able to access all of those objects but they do not get accessed by the servers. Now in my other view (that Parse.com built) when I run     `linkLabel.text = self.product[@"link"];` and then log it I get the value off of my data browser. So Basically I am doing something wrong and I need help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your data from parse ,you need to fire query and in return you get data for which you have provided a condition. Here's go with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958939/extracting-data-from-a-parse-com-class-and-into-an-nsarray) and [parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-retrieving/iOS) and also go for google. You will find your way to fetch your data from parse. After receiving data you could populate the label's or view controller you want to.